# Why did this character have to die?

Tags: tenet

At the end of *Tenet*, Neil saw that Volkov is entering underground (or saw him leaving the place inverted). So he decided to warn the protagonist and Ives about it by inverting himself to normal time. What I don't understand is that Neil could have waited a couple of minutes and invert himself afterwards (say 3 minutes before Volkov came). He would have had enough time to warn the protagonist and kill Volkov. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, like Neil says, "What has happened, has happened". Neil knew that Protagonist and Ives go in; and that means it's useless to warn them earlier (in their timeline; later in his inverted timeline), since they would still go in - whether because they ignore him or because he fails to talk to them.

He believed he could help them in contexts he did not know his help would fail.